# onLocationChanged Causes Crash, Black Screen

Tags: android, android-location, locationlistener

I have added a loader since my list class requires location to be updated.  However, upon setting the location in DDMS, the processes start closing, until the list of processes is blank, and the screen goes black.  The only error message thrown is below.  The crash is definitely caused by the onLocationChanged being called, but I have no idea how this could have happened.

```
E/InputQueue-JNI(335): channel '406d08f8 com.example.test/com.example.test.SplashActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
```

MyContent.Latitude and Longitude are static Floats, and the intent started worked before location services were added.

SplashActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    boolean     haveLocation;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        haveLocation = false;
        MyLoader lb = new MyLoader();
        lb.execute(this);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location currLoc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.getBestProvider(
                new Criteria(), false));
        if (currLoc == null)
            lm.requestSingleUpdate(new Criteria(), this, null);
        else
            onLocationChanged(currLoc);
    }

    public class MyLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args)
        {
               while (!haveLocation)
               {
                       try { wait(500); } catch (Exception e) {}
               }

               return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void arg)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                    ListActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        MyContent.LATITUDE = (float) location.getLatitude();
        MyContent.LONGITUDE = (float) location.getLongitude();
        haveLocation = true;
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.ListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".SplashActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are there any more lines the logcat to add context to the error?

Comment: No, that's the only message >= warn.  There are some dalvik_free messages on the debug level `D/dalvikvm(335): GC_CONCURRENT freed 410K, 52% free 2903K/6023K, external 505K/1017K, paused 13ms+11ms`

Comment: Could there be something about requestSingleUpdate that I do not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LocationManager lm = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
    lm.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);
else if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
    lm.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, this, null);
else {
    try {
        throw (new Exception("No location provider is available!"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Possibly the default "best" location provider was causing problems.  Now that I use the two constant providers, this works like a charm.  If anyone has an explanation as to why, that would be great, but this is a solution for anyone else who encounters this problem.